# Access Update query to change part of a field

Tags: ms-access

I have a field with two letter codes separated by ":" and I need to replace them with the name.  The fields can have any number of codes, and have a separate table with the codes and corresponding names.  The codes in one table might be RC or RC:BT, and the corresponding names in the other table would be Red Car or Blue Truck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own vba function and use this function in query. It will do require changes. So the query will look like

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeField = ResolveCodes(SomeField)
```

where ResolveCodes will be your function something like this:

```
Public Function ResolveCodes(SomeField as String) as String
Begin
' Some logic goes here:
' - split codes by ':'
' - resolve each code with DLookup or other OpenRecordset-based code
...
End Function
```